# Disable the overlay for admin using a feature?

Tags: users, importing-exporting

Every time i spawn a new website the first thing i need to do is disable the very slow overlay in /user/1/edit?destination=admin/people

[image]

Is there a way to export admin user settings each time after an install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a feature for this, but IMO it makes more sense to do this in an install profile, because you are just setting this once. One way or the other, you will need to add some code to the .install file of your install profile or feature, in the form of a hook_install implementation.

This is untested code but I believe it should work:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implement hook_install().
 */
function PROFILENAME_install() {
  user_save(user_load(1), array('data' => array('overlay' => 0)));
}
?>
```

Of course you need to replace 'PROFILENAME' with the name of your install profile or the name of your feature.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot. Seems like the a kick in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome. Please let us know if it worked for you, or if not, feel free to update the answer with code that does work :-)